# Good MapReduce examples

Tags: mapreduce

I couldn't think of any good examples other than the "how to count words in a long text with MapReduce" task. I found this wasn't the best example to give others an impression of how powerful this tool can be.

I'm not looking for code-snippets, really just "textual" examples.

Comment: I think a similar but much better example is to count words for all your text files you have on your computer. It's easier to understand and demonstrates the power of MapReduce.

Comment: To the last four questions that I searched for, I've found them closed as non constructive on this site. By fortune they have answers already. To the authors I endorse my gratitude and, as of now, there were more than 80 individuals that do not understand the closing policy. Not that it matters to others but I'm a professional programmer since the start of the 80's and, by now, I found myself asking the wrong questions :)

Comment: It is worth to have a look at MapReduce design patterns: e.g. some covered in [these slides](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse490h/08au/lectures/MapReduceDesignPatterns-UW2.pdf) and more can be seen in [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do)

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Map reduce is a framework that was developed to process massive amounts of data efficiently. 
For example, if we have 1 million records in a dataset, and it is stored in a relational representation - it is very expensive to derive values and perform any sort of transformations on these.

For Example In SQL, Given the Date of Birth, to find out How many people are of age > 30 for a million records would take a while, and this would only increase in order of magnitute when the complexity of the query increases. 
Map Reduce provides a cluster based implementation where data is processed in a distributed manner

Here is a wikipedia article explaining what [`map-reduce` is all about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

Another good example is Finding Friends via map reduce can be a powerful example to understand the concept, and
a well used use-case.

Personally, found [this link](http://stevekrenzel.com/finding-friends-with-mapreduce) quite useful to understand the concept

*Copying the explanation provided in the blog (In case the link goes stale)*

> ## Finding Friends
>
> MapReduce is a framework originally developed at Google that allows
>   for easy large scale distributed computing across a number of domains.
>   Apache Hadoop is an open source implementation.
>
> I'll gloss over the details, but it comes down to defining two
>   functions: a map function and a reduce function. The map function
>   takes a value and outputs key:value pairs. For instance, if we define
>   a map function that takes a string and outputs the length of the word
>   as the key and the word itself as the value then map(steve) would
>   return 5:steve and map(savannah) would return 8:savannah. You may have
>   noticed that the map function is stateless and only requires the input
>   value to compute it's output value. This allows us to run the map
>   function against values in parallel and provides a huge advantage.
>   Before we get to the reduce function, the mapreduce framework groups
>   all of the values together by key, so if the map functions output the
>   following key:value pairs:
>
> ```
> 3 : the
> 3 : and
> 3 : you
> 4 : then
> 4 : what
> 4 : when
> 5 : steve
> 5 : where
> 8 : savannah
> 8 : research
> ```
>
> They get grouped as:
>
> ```
> 3 : [the, and, you]
> 4 : [then, what, when]
> 5 : [steve, where]
> 8 : [savannah, research]
> ```
>
> Each of these lines would then be passed as an argument to the reduce
>   function, which accepts a key and a list of values. In this instance,
>   we might be trying to figure out how many words of certain lengths
>   exist, so our reduce function will just count the number of items in
>   the list and output the key with the size of the list, like:
>
> ```
> 3 : 3
> 4 : 3
> 5 : 2
> 8 : 2
> ```
>
> The reductions can also be done in parallel, again providing a huge
>   advantage. We can then look at these final results and see that there
>   were only two words of length 5 in our corpus, etc...
>
> The most common example of mapreduce is for counting the number of
>   times words occur in a corpus. Suppose you had a copy of the internet
>   (I've been fortunate enough to have worked in such a situation), and
>   you wanted a list of every word on the internet as well as how many
>   times it occurred.
>
> The way you would approach this would be to tokenize the documents you
>   have (break it into words), and pass each word to a mapper. The mapper
>   would then spit the word back out along with a value of `1`. The
>   grouping phase will take all the keys (in this case words), and make a
>   list of 1's. The reduce phase then takes a key (the word) and a list
>   (a list of 1's for every time the key appeared on the internet), and
>   sums the list. The reducer then outputs the word, along with it's
>   count. When all is said and done you'll have a list of every word on
>   the internet, along with how many times it appeared.
>
> Easy, right? If you've ever read about mapreduce, the above scenario
>   isn't anything new... it's the "Hello, World" of mapreduce. So here is
>   a real world use case (Facebook may or may not actually do the
>   following, it's just an example):
>
> Facebook has a list of friends (note that friends are a bi-directional
>   thing on Facebook. If I'm your friend, you're mine). They also have
>   lots of disk space and they serve hundreds of millions of requests
>   everyday. They've decided to pre-compute calculations when they can to
>   reduce the processing time of requests. One common processing request
>   is the "You and Joe have 230 friends in common" feature. When you
>   visit someone's profile, you see a list of friends that you have in
>   common. This list doesn't change frequently so it'd be wasteful to
>   recalculate it every time you visited the profile (sure you could use
>   a decent caching strategy, but then I wouldn't be able to continue
>   writing about mapreduce for this problem). We're going to use
>   mapreduce so that we can calculate everyone's common friends once a
>   day and store those results. Later on it's just a quick lookup. We've
>   got lots of disk, it's cheap.
>
> Assume the friends are stored as Person->[List of Friends], our
>   friends list is then:
>
> ```
> A -> B C D
> B -> A C D E
> C -> A B D E
> D -> A B C E
> E -> B C D
> ```
>
> Each line will be an argument to a mapper. For every friend in the
>   list of friends, the mapper will output a key-value pair. The key will
>   be a friend along with the person. The value will be the list of
>   friends. The key will be sorted so that the friends are in order,
>   causing all pairs of friends to go to the same reducer. This is hard
>   to explain with text, so let's just do it and see if you can see the
>   pattern. After all the mappers are done running, you'll have a list
>   like this:
>
> ```
> For map(A -> B C D) :
>
> (A B) -> B C D
> (A C) -> B C D
> (A D) -> B C D
>
> For map(B -> A C D E) : (Note that A comes before B in the key)
>
> (A B) -> A C D E
> (B C) -> A C D E
> (B D) -> A C D E
> (B E) -> A C D E
> For map(C -> A B D E) :
>
> (A C) -> A B D E
> (B C) -> A B D E
> (C D) -> A B D E
> (C E) -> A B D E
> For map(D -> A B C E) :
>
> (A D) -> A B C E
> (B D) -> A B C E
> (C D) -> A B C E
> (D E) -> A B C E
> And finally for map(E -> B C D):
>
> (B E) -> B C D
> (C E) -> B C D
> (D E) -> B C D
> Before we send these key-value pairs to the reducers, we group them by their keys and get:
>
> (A B) -> (A C D E) (B C D)
> (A C) -> (A B D E) (B C D)
> (A D) -> (A B C E) (B C D)
> (B C) -> (A B D E) (A C D E)
> (B D) -> (A B C E) (A C D E)
> (B E) -> (A C D E) (B C D)
> (C D) -> (A B C E) (A B D E)
> (C E) -> (A B D E) (B C D)
> (D E) -> (A B C E) (B C D)
> ```
>
> Each line will be passed as an argument to a reducer. The reduce
>   function will simply intersect the lists of values and output the same
>   key with the result of the intersection. For example, reduce((A B) ->
>   (A C D E) (B C D)) will output (A B) : (C D) and means that friends A
>   and B have C and D as common friends.
>
> The result after reduction is:
>
> ```
> (A B) -> (C D)
> (A C) -> (B D)
> (A D) -> (B C)
> (B C) -> (A D E)
> (B D) -> (A C E)
> (B E) -> (C D)
> (C D) -> (A B E)
> (C E) -> (B D)
> (D E) -> (B C)
> ```
>
> Now when D visits B's profile, we can quickly look up `(B D)` and see
>   that they have three friends in common, `(A C E)`.

Comment: Another example would be analyzing the weather data from across the world. Finding the Max and min for any given region. This is a very good example.

Comment: Generating all of those intermediate tuples and then later checking the intersection for all, isn't that tedious? Wouldn't it be better to just generate all possible friend pairs, like AB AC BC etc and just pass these pairs with the entire friend lists, just of the two friends in the pair, to a particular machine and let it calculate the intersection? What am I missing here?

Comment: @GrowinMan, I think the point is in scalability, parallelism, and size of the whole set of data. For small problems, MapReduce is not adapted, but for huge sets of data (think millions of people with hundreds of friends each).

Comment: What if A visit E's profile? There's no (A, E) in the final result though they have friends in common.

Comment: @Pinch that's because A and E are not friends themselves. In that case this approach seems indeed insufficient (unless you take into account that A or E could hide their friendlist for non-friends:) )

Comment: hello karthikr... can you tell me where does the grouping happen as you have specified in your answer..3 : [the, and, you]?

Comment: does it happen in the partitioner and sort phase?

Comment: @karthikr : I'm confused about the grouping phase. Map and Reduce can obviously be ran in parallel but what about the grouping phase ? It must be done in a single thread or am I missing something ?

Comment: I don't know why people keep giving extremely simple examples to explain such a powerful tool ?

Answer (score 5):

One set of familiar operations that you can do in MapReduce is the set of normal SQL operations: SELECT, SELECT WHERE, GROUP BY, etc.

Another good example is matrix multiplication, where you pass one row of M and the entire vector x and compute one row of M * x.

Comment: The matrix multiplication example doesn't have a reduce phase and, consequently, is not a *"good example"*.

Answer (score 3):

From time to time I present MR concepts to people. I find processing tasks familiar to people and then map them to the MR paradigm.

Usually I take two things:

1. Group By / Aggregations. Here the advantage of the shuffling stage is clear. An explanation that shuffling is also distributed sort + an explanation of distributed sort algorithm also helps.
2. Join of two tables. People working with DB are familiar with the concept and its scalability problem. Show how it can be done in MR.

Comment: to explian to non nerds i use the children method:
you have a bunch of eager kids, and many many cards.

you give each kid an amount of cards telling them to sort them by back of card *deck, then by number/picture then by suit- i.e. the map function

each kid finishes and brings to an allotted set of adults, two at a time. each adult  "reduces" the pile into one pile, and then each two adults give to a free adult there card stacks.

that is by definition the reduce function that can be run more than one time according to the number of kids/stacks.

most people get it on the first try